# Find and Update Multiple Sheets with a Userform

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have a `userform` which is sending data to multiple sheets within the same workbook depending on certain criteria. `ws1`, `ws2`, `ws3` and `ws4` ws1 is the mastersheet which will contain all entries, and the 3 corresponding worksheets are where the information will end up depending on the criteria outlay.

What I am looking to do now however, is insert an update function. Each line is given a reference. If a line qualifies for ws2 then it is given a second reference.

The code to place my data within the sheets is below. I have thought about using a foundcell function to find and then update the reference number however I can only get it to update the master sheet and not update the same entry on the other sheets 1 or 2 sheets the entry may be included.

Im not sure if it is possible also but I am looking to see if VBA can also still use the qualification criteria to delete the entry from lets say ws2 and move to ws3 if the update changes the qualifying criteria. Can anyone help?

Code for Data Entry

```
Private Sub EnterDetails_Click()

Dim mRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim Nextnum As Long
Dim Xnum As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("MasterData")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("X")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("A")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("C")

Nextnum = GetNextId(Sheets("MasterData"), "A")
Xnum = GetNextId(Sheets("X"), "AB")

Dim TargetWorksheets As Variant
'16 qualifying scenarios to determine where the data will be sent

    Select Case True
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)

        Case Else: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1)
    End Select

For Each ws In TargetWorksheets

'find first empty row in worksheets
    mRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'copy userform info data to the qualifying database sheets
    ws.Cells(mRow, 1).Value = Nextnum
    ws.Cells(mRow, 2).Value = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 3).Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM:SS")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 4).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "WW"))
    ws.Cells(mRow, 5).Value = DateSerial(Year(ws.Cells(mRow, 2)), Month(ws.Cells(mRow, 2)), 1)
    ws.Cells(mRow, 6).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "YYYY"))
    ws.Cells(mRow, 7).Value = 1
    ws.Cells(mRow, 8).Value = TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000)
    ws.Cells(mRow, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBrd.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("G:H"), 2, False)
    ws.Cells(mRow, 10).Value = Application.UserName
               If ComboBrd.Value = "Myson" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCom.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("L:N"), 2, False) Else
               If ComboBrd.Value = "Purmo" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCom.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("P:R"), 2, False) Else
                   If ComboBrd.Value = "Vogel & Noot" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCom.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("P:R"), 2, False)
    ws.Cells(mRow, 12).Value = Format(Me.TxtRD.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 13).Value = ComboPD.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 14).Value = ComboNP.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 15).Value = ComboBrd.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 16).Value = ComboCom.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 17).Value = TxtAdditional.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 18).Value = Format(Me.TxtDD.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws.Cells(mRow, 19).Value = TxtBn.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 20).Value = TxtFS.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 21).Value = ComboPrGp.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 22).Value = ComboIss.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 23).Value = TxtUn.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 24).Value = TxtWt.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 25).Value = TxtIn.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 26).Value = TxtDetails.Value
    ws.Cells(mRow, 27).Value = TxtSp.Value

Select Case True

        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: ws.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = Xnum
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: ws.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = Xnum
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: ws.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = Xnum
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: ws.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = Xnum

End Select

   Next ws

        TxtRD.Value = ""
        ComboBrd.Value = ""
        ComboPD.Value = ""
        ComboNP.Value = ""
        ComboBrd.Value = ""
        ComboCom.Value = ""
        TxtAdditional.Value = ""
        TxtDD.Value = ""
        TxtBn.Value = ""
        TxtFS.Value = ""
        ComboPrGp.Value = ""
        ComboIss.Value = ""
        TxtUn.Value = ""
        TxtWt.Value = ""
        TxtIn.Value = ""
        TxtDetails.Value = ""
        TxtSp.Value = ""

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Code for Updating

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("MasterData")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("X")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("A")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("C")

mysearch = Me.Search.Value

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterData")
        Set searchRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = Me.RD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = Me.DD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Me.PD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = Me.NP.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = Me.Brd.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = Me.Com.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 25).Value = Me.Details.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 20).Value = Me.Prgp.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 21).Value = Me.Iss.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Me.CVal.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = Me.Un.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = Me.Wt.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = Me.In.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 26).Value = Me.Sp.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = Me.FS.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = Me.LN.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 16).Value = Me.Add.Value

    Else
         MsgBox "ID does not exist."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you come up with a [mcve]? Note in particular the "M". You gave a wall of code, one which depends on the existence of certain worksheets and userforms, whose structure can only be (partially) inferred. Surely there must be some simpler way to illustrate the problem that you are having.

Comment: The update code (which seems to be what you are asking about -- why even show the other code?) doesn't even attempt to do anything with `ws2`, `ws3`, and `ws4` (after they have been set). Of course that code doesn't modify the other sheets -- it doesn't even try. You seem to have given a lot of code which works, but neglected to give the code which *doesn't* work, which is the only code that is really important for the question.

Comment: @JohnColeman The code was used to give a fuller understanding of the structure. The update code yes it works. Nothing is "not working" my question which is stated "Im not sure if it is possible also but I am looking to see if VBA can also still use the qualification criteria to delete the entry from lets say ws2 and move to ws3 if the update changes the qualifying criteria. Can anyone help?" In otherwords update all entries a reference number is used within the sheet and if the qualifying criteria changes for example if comboNP is now an "N" to move it to the the other worksheet etc

Comment: It isn't clear what is preventing you from doing what you want to do. Of course you can use VBA to do things like update values in multiple worksheets (you even seem to know how to do this in the first sub that you show) or move a value from one worksheet to another. Give an example of code which *attempts* to do what you want to do but fails. That might give a better understanding of what the problem is.